# Rails - debugging selenium-webdriver 404 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Rspec, Capybara and Selenium (WebDriver) to test my Rails app, a simple online store. Here's a simplified version of the spec that's failing:

```
describe 'Team Order' do

  let(:product) { Product.last }

  before do
    create :product_with_color_and_size
  end

  it 'goes to product page', js: true do
    visit add_team_order_path(product)
    expect(page).to have_content(product.name)
  end

end
```

Specifically, the Selenium-driven Firefox window displays my application's 404 page, causing the check for the product's name to fail.

When I call `debugger` from within the `it` block and query `Product.last` I can see the Product in question in the test db. So I suspect Selenium is hitting the wrong instance of my app...or something.

Not sure if this is relevant, but the browser is pointing at `http://127.0.0.1:49736/products/product-10/add-team-order` (although the port changes between rspec runs).

My question is, what can I do to verify that it's hitting the right instance? If it isn't, what steps can I take to fix is?

### Edit:

database_cleaner configuration in spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before :suite do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that database_cleaner was clashing with my `js: true` specs. A nice summary:

> The problem is always the same: the tests are being wrapped in database transactions, so any code running outside the actual test process (like, say, a server process servicing a Selenium-driven browser request) does not see the database fixture I’ve so carefully assembled.

More info, along with my solution, here: http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/